# Save data from an LCD KeyPad Shield to an SD card

Tags: c++, windows, arduino

I'm developing a project that requires to save data from a sensor that is connected to an LCD keypad shield. The information should be saved in a file on an SD card.

My code:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
#include <SD.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd(8, 9, 4, 5, 6, 7);

int buttons;
File myFile;
//name of the file
char nombrefichero[12];
int i = 1;
int exist = LOW ;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  //check the sd card adapter
  Serial.print("Iniciando SD ...");
  if (!SD.begin(53)) {
    Serial.println("No se pudo inicializar");
    return;
  }
  Serial.println("inicializacion exitosa");
}

void loop() {
  // use the buttons of the lcd keypad shield in analog 0
  buttons = analogRead(0);
  //button right
  if(buttons < 50) {
    count ++;
    nuevo();
  }
  //button select
  if(buttons < 790) {
    capturar();
  }
}

void capturar() {
  myFile = SD.open(nombrefichero, FILE_WRITE);//abrimos  el archivo
  if (myFile) {
    Serial.print("Escribiendo SD: ");
    int sensor1 = analogRead(0);
    int sensor2 = analogRead(1);
    int sensor3 = analogRead(2);
    myFile.print(millis());
    myFile.print(",");
    myFile.print(sensor1);
    myFile.print(",");
    myFile.print(sensor2);
    myFile.print(",");
    myFile.println(sensor3);
    myFile.close(); //cerramos el archivo
    Serial.print("Tiempo(ms)=");
    Serial.print(millis());
    Serial.print(",sensor1=");
    Serial.print(sensor1);
    Serial.print(",sensor2=");
    Serial.print(sensor2);
    Serial.print(",sensor3=");
    Serial.println(sensor3);
  } else {
    // if the file didn't open, print an error:
    Serial.println("Error al abrir el archivo");
  }
  delay(1000);
}

void nuevo() {
  while (exist == LOW) {
    sprintf(nombrefichero, "M%d.txt",i);
    //generate autoincrement number of file
    if(SD.exists(nombrefichero)) {
      i = i+1;
      myFile = SD.open(nombrefichero, FILE_WRITE);
      if (myFile) {
        Serial.println("Archivo nuevo, Escribiendo encabezado(fila 1)");
        myFile.println("Tiempo(ms),Sensor1,Sensor2,Sensor3");
        myFile.close();
      } else {
        exist = HIGH;
        Serial.println("Error creando el archivo");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I need to capture the information of the sensor when I press the select button and when the right button is pressed create a new file.

In this method, in this line  **if(SD.exists(nombrefichero))** if I put the **!** before **SD.exists** the files are created infinitely but if I leave it as is without the **!** the button does nothing.

```
void nuevo() {
  while (exist == LOW) {
    sprintf(nombrefichero, "M%d.txt",i);
    if(SD.exists(nombrefichero)) {
      i = i+1;
      myFile = SD.open(nombrefichero, FILE_WRITE);
      if (myFile) {
        Serial.println("Archivo nuevo, Escribiendo encabezado(fila 1)");
        myFile.println("Tiempo(ms),Sensor1,Sensor2,Sensor3");
        myFile.close();
      } else {
        exist = HIGH;
        Serial.println("Error creando el archivo");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using an Arduino Mega 2560 and SD card adapter.

Comment: I need source code of SD.exist(...) function. Please post your  code.

Comment: `if(!SD.exists(nombrefichero))
  {
      myFile = SD.open(nombrefichero, FILE_WRITE);
      if (myFile) {
        Serial.println("Archivo nuevo, Escribiendo encabezado(fila 1)");
        while(exist == LOW){
          sprintf(nombrefichero, "%d.txt",i);
          i = i+1;
        myFile.println("Tiempo(ms),Sensor1,Sensor2,Sensor3");
        }
        myFile.close();
      } else {
        exist = HIGH;
        Serial.println("Error creando el archivo");
      }
  }`